# How can I change the color of only the command I type, and not the output following it?

Tags: command-line, terminal, terminal.app

`export PS1='\[\033[1;31m\]\u\[\033[0m\]:\[\033[4;31m\]\W\[\033[0m\] \[\033[0;33m\]\$'`

This is what my prompt looks like at the moment. However, this paints everything *after* the $ in yellow too. I want only the $ and the command I enter to be yellow, and the output to have "no color".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your shell is `bash` and you don't have any other scripts that rely on `PROMPT_COMMAND`, you can use [bash-preexec](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec) to do this. Place the following at the bottom of your `.bashrc`:

```
. ~/.bash-preexec.sh
preexec() { echo -ne '\033[0m'; }
```